# Orchard Cannot access to media file - access is denied

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to insert picture in Orchard amdin page, but I get an error

```
An unhandled exception has occurred and the request was terminated. Please refresh the page. If the error persists, go back

The folder could not be created at path: . System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\Projects\MySite.Web\Media\Default' is denied. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj) at Contrib.MediaFolder.Services.RemoteStorageProvider.ListFolders(String path)

System.ArgumentException: The folder could not be created at path: . System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\Projects\MySite.Site.Web\Media\Default' is denied. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj) at Contrib.MediaFolder.Services.RemoteStorageProvider.ListFolders(String path) at Contrib.MediaFolder.Services.RemoteStorageProvider.ListFolders(String path) at Orchard.Media.Services.MediaService.GetMediaFolders(String relativePath) at Orchard.MediaPicker.Controllers.AdminController.Index(String name, String mediaPath) at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__12() at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

I have set all permissions for all users (IUSR, SYSTEm, Administartor, Users) to Media folder, but still getting error. Please, help me to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked which user your app pool is running under?  Make sure this user has access to modify that folder.

Comment: Another thing to check is that it's not simply read-only, which is something that is easy to overlook.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, copying the contents of the media folder to a new folder, deleting the media folder and renaming the new folder to Media and set permissions for IIS_IUSRS, seemingly solved the problem.